# Producing ODT from LaTeX using htlatex

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, tex4ht, htlatex

The command `htlatex filename "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo"` produces an ODT file with 2 major problems:

- All cross references are lost; and
- Figures not displayed correctly in size.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

`htlatex` is not a right tool to produce ODT files using TeX4ht, it is necessary to use `make4ht`:

```
make4ht -f odt filename.tex
```

`make4ht` fixes some issues in the generated ODT file, cross-referencing support is among them.

Regarding images, TeX4ht cannot guess image sizes, so it needs special `.xbb` file for each included image. You can generate them using the following commands:

```
ebb -x *.png
ebb -x *.jpg
```